# I accidentally clicked "split text to columns" in Data Function

Tags: google-sheets

I accidentally clicked "split text to columns" using the Data function for one of my cells in a Google Sheet I am working on. How do I return text to how I originally entered it?

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot undo and there are not a lot of changes in the file, you can select File->See revision history and get the edit saved prior to the split.

If neither of these work, you can use get it manually via this formula, modified to meet you range and separator:

```
=CONCATENATE(H3, " ", J3, " ", K3, " ", L3)
```

And then Copy the contents of that cell to your clipboard and *Past special->Paste **values** only* to get the string back.